# Error with ActiveWorkbook Path VBA macro Excel 2013?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

i want to create a vba macro for excel 2013. this vba macro must be available for all excel files, i make a search in the internet and i found that i must put the code in Excel add-in, so  i try to make a code for event opening of excel; the code is the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 If (ActiveWorkbook.Path = "C:\GED\TEMP") Then
     MsgBox "Hello"
 End If
End Sub
```

the problem is that when i open excel file, vba dont know the active workbook because it opens the file in XLSTART first then my current file, so i have the following error:Run-time error '91 ': Object variable or With block variable not set. So any idea please; i should check the path of the workbook at the opening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need Application-level events to trap the opening of any workbook. Replace your code with this:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents app As Excel.Application

Private Sub app_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    If UCase$(Wb.Path) = "C:\GED\TEMP" Then MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Set app = Application
End Sub
```

Comment: rory please if i have an other event likeWorkbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) what i should do ?

Comment: Use `Private Sub app_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)`. If you select `app` in the left hand dropdown at the top of the code window, the right hand dropdown will show you all the available events and selecting one will create the routine declaration for you.

Comment: you didn't say where to put the code , in a module, this workbook, other... ?

Comment: In ThisWorkbook. [It was implied by the fact I said 'replace your code' when the existing code was in the ThisWorkbook module. ;)]

Comment: Hi Rory, thank you again for your answer, i want to write in the statusbar of Excel 2013 so i have puted the following code in app_Workbook:
Private Sub app_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    app.DisplayStatusBar = True
    If UCase$(Wb.Path) = "C:\GED\TEMP" Then 
 app.StatusBar = "ok"
    Else
 app.StatusBar = "ko"
    EndIF
   
End Sub
but i have always error in the method statusbar of _Application.
it takes always false i dont know why please any idea or help.
thank you again